# Proving that $ 0.01n^2-100n = Θ(n^2) $

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I apologize in advance for my mathematical incompetence, but I have a hard time to solve that task. I need to prove that $ 0.01n^2-100n = Θ(n^2) $. I think, based on definitions, and other tasks that I understand how to prove $O$, $Ω$ and $Θ$, at least on simpler examples.

The defitinion: $c1 > 0$, $c2 > 0$, $n$ is a natural number: $0 ≤ c1*g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c2*g(n)$

Here I have two main issues:

1. Firstly, I think that the upper bound could be only $ n $.

$0.01n^2-100n ≤ 1n$

when we have for example $n = 1$ (knowing that $n$ by the definition needs to be a natural number, and $c1$ needs to be $> 0$ ), so we have something that is true:

-99.99 ≤ 1

whatever $ n $ and $ c2$ I think of the above equation is true. So we don't really need $n^2$ here...

and second thing:

2) How I can choose the lower bound so that it can be $ ≤ $ than $ 0.01n^2-100n $ when my $c1$ needs to be $> 0$. I cannot put here anything that could be more negative than $0.01n^2-100n$.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: As to point 1).  It has to be true for all sufficiently large $n$.  Try it for $n=10^6$

Comment: Oh, that's true... You have opened my eyes to bigger numbers. Now I will be more cautious. Thanks for that! Do you have maybe any idea when it comes to point no. 2 and this negative number?

Comment: Any number between $0$ and $.01$ will work.  Look at user's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$0.001 n^2\le0.01n^2-100n\le 0.01n^2$$

indeed

$$0.001 n^2\le0.01n^2-100n \implies 0.0099n^2\ge100n \implies n\ge \frac{100}{0.0099}$$

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! But when for example n = 1, then $ 0.001 n^2 ≤ 0.01n^2−100n $ cannot be true. Then we have 0.001 ≤ -99.99. Can you agree with that? Comments no. 2: OK, but I think I understand now. We need to stick to bigger numbers when we want to prove that, as @saulspatz wrote, then it will work for both sides.

Comment: @Mary yes of course but we need that the inequality holds for any $n\ge n_0$ and in that case it suffices to take  $n_0> \frac{100}{0.0099}$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Now I slowly get it :).